# Код вне тела if, выполняется при несоблюдении условия

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global donates_get
    if message.author == client.user and message.guild is None:
        return
    sql_conn = sqlite3.connect("donates.db")
    db = sql_conn.cursor()
```

Первое условие проверяет, является ли отправитель пользователем и пишет ли он в личные сообщения. Если вы знаете альтернативный способ проверки на личку, отпишитесь.
Суть в том что даже если пользователь пишет на сервере, то работа кода всё равно продолжается. Как это исправить?

Comment: Так внесите код под if

Comment: Всё равно продолжается при несоблюдении.

Comment: У вас путаница с логическими операторами. Сейчас код работает так: `ЕСЛИ автор сообщения == бот И гильдии нет ДЕЛАТЬ return` Скорее всего вы перепутали И ИЛИ. С `or` должна логика работать так как вы хотели.

Comment: Но ведь в таком случае бот будет реагировать на сообщения с сервера если отправитель == клиент юзер, а мне надо чтобы второе условие обязательно соблюдалась